# setting target for disclosure button on subclassed UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've created a subclass of UITableViewCell to create some custom appearance and UI functionality ('swipe to reveal delete button').

Some of the cells are disclosure/detail disclosure type, and have a UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure etc added manually. I cannot use the table view controllers' UITableViewCellAccessory for row at index path method.

The question is, how do I set the target of these manually added buttons so that they correctly send the didSelectRowAtIndexPath to their table view controller?

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct way of setting an action the accessory disclosure button. Though you can do this with delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

See if that works.